# How to create a function which calls a tag in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to create a function in reactjs that will have a tag like this:

```
export class Counter extends Component {
    anyFunction() {
        return <h1>Hello there</h1>;
    }
    render() {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            {this.anyFunction()}
          </React.Fragment>
           );
    }
}
```

is it possible? I want to call the tag in a function then want to call as a return statement.

Comment: Just write it. Your code seems correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not create inside class or functional component you need to create second component

```
const AnyFunction = (props) => (
  <h1>Hello there</h1>
)

export class Counter extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <AnyFunction />
          </React.Fragment>
           );
    }
}
```

For conditional render

```
const AnyFunction = (props) => (
  <h1>Hello there</h1>
)

export class Counter extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            { num === 1 && <AnyFunction /> }
            { num === 1 ? <AnyFunction /> : <AnyOtherFunction /> }
          </React.Fragment>
           );
    }
}
```

Comment: and what if i wanted to add an if statement that if num === 1 ? <Anyfunction />

Comment: @SankalpBhatia i have updated my post and please upvote if its help full

Comment: @SankalpBhatia you can also do if else
`{ num === 1 ? <AnyFunction /> : <AnyOtherFunction /> }`

Comment: conditional render is not working with a custom tag. I created a <HelpBlock> tag with another .js file and its not returning as expected

Comment: @SankalpBhatia please provide more details how did you created another.js

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
export class Counter extends Component {

    render() {
    var someTag = <h1>Hello there</h1>;
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            {someTag}
          </React.Fragment>
           );
    }
}
```